# Are there any libraries for capturing NVTX events without using nsys (NSight Systems)?

Tags: profiling, metrics, telemetry, nvtx

NSight Systems is a really really great tool for profiling code, but it's not something we can run in production due to constraints on how it attaches to processes, functional safety certification, etc. Given a large codebase that is already annotated with NVTX annotations, are there any libraries for processing the NVTX events, oriented towards gathering metrics in production code?